# changing image position using css

Tags: javascript, html, css

I would like to change the position of this image and put to the right of the content
do you know how? and i also don't understand why the image outside the article shouldn't it be inside? Thank you [image] can i do that?

I wrote this code:
`your text`

```css
section {
  display       : flex;
  margin-left   : auto;
  margin-right  : auto;
  margin-bottom : 20px;
  margin-top    : 20px;
  height        : 50vh;
  width         : 60vw;
  border-radius : 3px;
  box-shadow    : -10px -10px 15px rgba(255,255,255, 0.5)
                ,  10px  10px 15px rgba( 70, 70, 70, 0.12);
  }
.art-fle1 , 
.art-fle2 {
  height     : 90%;
  width      : 100%;
  margin-top : auto;
  }
.content-text {
  width        : 50%;
  height       : 80%;
  padding-left : 15px;
  }
.burger {
  width : 270px;
  float : right;
  }
```

```HTML
<main>
  <section class="first-section">
    <article class="art-fle1" class="a1">
      <div class="continer A">
        <div class="content-text">
          <h1>Header 1</h1>
          <p>
            Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quaerat corporis voluptate vel ab consectetur repudiandae sunt accusantium. Perspiciatis, minima voluptatem!
          </p>
        </div>
        <div class="burger">
          <img src="food/burger.jpg" alt="" width="270px">
        </div>
      </div>
    </article>
  </section>
</main>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign    `.container-A`    as    `display: flex`    with    `justify-content: space-between`. You don't really need a    `div` to contain the burger image either, but I included it to make the DOM as similar to your original question as possible.

I'm linking the mdn web docs for    `justify-content`    and
`align-items`    as well. Hope this helps!

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/justify-content
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/align-items

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Stack Overflow</title>
    <style>
      section {
        display       : flex;
        margin-left   : auto;
        margin-right  : auto;
        margin-bottom : 20px;
        margin-top    : 20px;
        height        : 50vh;
        width         : 60vw;
        border-radius : 3px;
        box-shadow    : -10px -10px 15px rgba(255,255,255, 0.5)
                      ,  10px  10px 15px rgba( 70, 70, 70, 0.12);
        }
      .art-fle1 , 
      .art-fle2 {
        height     : 90%;
        width      : 100%;
        margin-top : auto;
        }
      .content-text {
        width        : 50%;
        height       : 80%;
        padding-left : 15px;
        }
      .burger {
        width : 270px;
        float : right;
        } 
      .container-A {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <main>
      <section class="first-section">
        <article class="art-fle1" class="a1">
          <div class="container-A">
            <div class="content-text">
              <h1>Header 1</h1>
              <p>
                Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quaerat corporis voluptate vel ab consectetur repudiandae sunt accusantium. Perspiciatis, minima voluptatem!
              </p>
            </div>
            <div class="burger">
              <img src="food/burger.jpeg" alt="" width="270px">
            </div>
          </div>
        </article>
      </section>
    </main>
  </body>
</html>
```